# Multiply useQuery on one page, why undefined result?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

I need too use useQuery a few times to get different data from db.
So I call:

```
const {data: var1} = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {variable: {content1});

const {data: var2} = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {variable: {content2});

const {data: var3} = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {variable: {content3});

const {data: var4} = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {variable: {content4});

const {data: var5} = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {variable: {content5});
```

Still I can't get the result of useQuery (on backend (nest.js) I see correct response in console, but cant see it on frontend(react.js))

Help me, please. I am missed something

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mre] and their linked pages. We need to be able to duplicate the problem from the code you give us, and currently we can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 syntax errors that may be the problem, first you probably need a space between `const` and `{data...` and `variable` should be a plural `variables`. also you are missing a curly bracket inside `useQuery`

Try this?

```js
const { data: var1 } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, { variables: { content1 } });

console.log(var1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is just a pseudo code to show what query (MY_QUERY) is same, just used 5 times. 
All things you mentioned are okay in real code